# Repeated tasks in Orgmode: how to avoid repeated tasks in the past

Tags: org-mode

Basically, the problem is that when you are behind a "repetitive" weekly task, let's say, one that should have been done 3 weeks ago, and you mark it as DONE, it will move it to the following week, not the week ahead in the future with respect to the current week. So I find myself marking the task DONE as many times as weeks. Is there a way to tell orgmode to skip the past weeks? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different types of repeat dates in org mode.

- a simple `+1w`, just moves the date forward one week when done
- `++1w` moves the date forward one week at a time until a date in the future is found
- `.+1w` makes the next date one week from the day you mark it done.

It sounds like you want the second or third version.

See the section of the org manual on "Repeated tasks" to get more details.